# Properly way to hash a message with salt and iteration count?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, salt

I need to hash a message with random salt and iteration count.

Here is the way I used (Way-1)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] message;
    byte[] randomSalt;
    int iterations = 1000;

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] hash = digest.digest(message);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        // randomSalt used multi-times
        hash = digest.digest(ArrayUtils.appendArrays(randomSalt, hash));
    }

    // Final result:  randomSalt + hash
}
```

However, I found another way people used (Way-2)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] message;
    byte[] randomSalt;
    int iterations = 1000;

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    // Use randomSalt Once
    digest.update(randomSalt);

    byte[] hash = digest.digest(message);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        // randomSalt Are Not used here
        hash = digest.digest(hash);
    }

    // Final result:  randomSalt + hash
}
```

Of course, two way produce different outputs.

The mainly different between Way-1 and Way-2 is in Way-1, salt is used Multi-times.

**Question**: Which way do you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this  iterated hashing? If it's a password you really don't want to use a hash like sha-256, you want one optimized for passwords like pbkdf2 or bcrypt.

Comment: @PaulRubel: Thanks!. I am not using it for hashing password!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them.

If you're **hashing passwords** to produce an encryption key, then you should use available standardized schemes such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2. They are specifically designed for this purpose. For example, scrypt and Argon2 will use a high amount of memory so that cracking speedup through ASICs cannot be achieved.

If you're **hashing a message for authentication** purposes as in MAC, then you only need to hash twice. HMAC is a standardized scheme in that regard which for example prevents length-extension attacks that would have been possible with the underlying hash function alone. Having multiple iterations doesn't add security unless the HMAC key is of low entropy (such as a password), in which case, you would need to derive a proper key with the first suggestion of using a password-based key derivation function.

If you just need an **integrity checking** value, then doing multiple iterations is useless and a single hash of the message would suffice (it doesn't even have to be salted). Integrity doesn't have a security purpose and only protects against accidental manipulation. Multiple iterations on the other hand are usually used to slow down some operation which is not what you want with integrity checking. If you need to detect malicious manipulation, then you *need* to use a MAC, which is nothing more than a keyed-hash in case of HMAC.

If you need a hash of a message for **signing**, then multiple iterations also don't provide additional security. A hash for signing is only used to reduce the size of the message to sign. The actual signature security is provided by the asymmetric algorithm and not the hashing algorithm, so multiple iterations don't add additional security here. If the signature algorithm is broken, then an attacker can simply create a hash of the manipulated message and sign it.

Those are only some of the uses of hash functions, but they are the most popular. Iterated hash functions are only useful in 1 of the 4 cases.

Comment: I plan to use it for integrity checking. Thank you!

Comment: I see. I've extended my answer a bit. By the way, your Way-2 is very similar to PBKDF1, but with the position of salt and message switched. It's not recommended for use today. Way-1 is familiar, but I can't place it.

Comment: By the way, if you want to be guaranteed to detect single bit non-malicious manipulation of the message, then you should use CRC, because hashes may still produce collisions for single-bit differences, but CRC will not. Of course, it's rather improbable with SHA-256

Comment: @ArtjomB. If hashing passwords with PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2 for user password authentication, saved in a DB on a production server what delay is both secure and reasonable WRT server load?

Comment: @zaph It really depends on the application and the patience of its users. 100 - 500 ms is common I would say, but it should be timed on the actual server hardware. Making an estimation about memory in case of scrypt/Argon2 is tricky. There are a lot of options to tune it. I'd say what ever is reasonable, but not too easy. The worst case server load must be considered in this case.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The problem I am wrestling with is using 100+ ms on each login, on any kind of busy site, that could be essentially a denial of service attack. There is a world of difference between an HMAC at ~ 2 us and PBKDF2 at 100 ms. And the attacker, if offline, may be running on a high-end GPU where 100 ms is substantially reduced. Running on a single user device, a phone, 100 ms is no problem but a server is another animal. It can also be difficult to convince server developers that 100-500 ms is acceptable.

Comment: @zaph I understand your struggle. (D)DoS detection/mitigation is always an additional measure that has to be employed, more so with slow login procedures. If deployed, it can help reduce the effectiveness of other exploits such as when there are timing differences between multiple login attempts which reveal the password after some time. Or a padding oracle attack can be severely slowed down by those measures. There is a lot of care to be taken with operational security.

Comment: @ArtjomB. What I am wrestling with is how to answer SO questions WRT PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc delay. Most answers on SO are to use just a salted hash, that is what I am fighting. Perhaps recommend 100ms and suggest that if there are performance issues to reduce as needed? Even 1ms is much better than ~2 us  without iteration. The LInkedIn breach recovered 100 million passwords in 72 hours, just adding 3 orders of magnitude to the hashing process would push that out to about 10 years. (P.S. I don't run a server, I'm a retired developer.)